# Error MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aws-lambda

I have a very annoying issue with my aws lambda functions.

Sometimes, requests fail due to the following error. I don't know the reason, this is very randomly as I think 95% of my request succeed but the 5% that fails cause severe damages and clearly prevent my app to work properly.

```js
Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

Yet in mongodb atlas => Network access, I put ip address to `0.0.0.0` .

Here is my current situation

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let conn = null;

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
module.exports = function connect() {
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = mongoose.connect(uri, {
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 10000,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      keepAlive: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(() => mongoose);

    // `await`ing connection after assigning to the `conn` variable
    // to avoid multiple function calls creating new connections
    await conn;
  }

  return conn;
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something you should take up with Mongo Atlas Support as there should be no blacklisting at all on 0.0.0.0 as you correctly mention. I do note that that is just a suggestion as to what the problem is and may not be the actual issue. In that light, here are some points I'd like to make:

- Unless you have set [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) Lambda will spin up as many functions as is required to handle your load, this can easily overwhelm the number of max connections to your Mongo Atlas cluster. Have you checked whether you are simply exceeding the max connections?
- Have you considered placing your lambdas in a VPC? Lambdas by default have access to the Internet. If you put your lambda function in a VPC private subnet, they lose their default access to the Internet but can now use a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance to access the Internet. The advantage of this is that you can assign a static IP address to this NAT Gateway/Instance. This means you can tell Mongo Atlas to accept only connections from this IP address thus making your database more secure -- no need to whitelist `0.0.0.0` -- See [this article](https://matthewleak.medium.com/aws-lambda-functions-with-a-static-ip-89a3ada0b471) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked my logs on both aws and mongodb. I am in test/dev mode so it'very unlikely I've reached max connection limit on both lambda and mongodb atlas. However I think sometimes aws lambda randomly fail to connect to mongodb cluster. So now, I am looking for a solution to force my lambda function to retry to connect to my mongodb cluster if the initial connection fail. Any suugestion ?